# Scrubbing grandchild’s timeline causes previously unloaded grandchild swf’s sound to play, interfering with sound of currently playing grandchild swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

what problem am I facing?
I have a parent file. It loads a child by name of overview file. Overview file further loads many (grandchild) files. I have a timeline scrubber on parent file. It scrubs both child as well as grandchild files. The problem is if I load a grandchild file, unload it. then load next grandchild file and scrub the timeline, the sound of previously loaded grandchild file starts playing. How can I stop it?? Please help, I have tried hard but I could not solve, I am amateur, no formal programming knowledge. Thanks.

I am providing a link http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/RA9RziNuDlC2MPj%2F11DoLLkW4A7ota%2B4KmmbltoalaeH%2FYEipSU22U2tlMBOBefBFc1RnhYpLCv3pRyAfFLxfA in case someone wants to see code.

To reproduce error: Open parent file. click on armored link, then click on home button to unload it. Now, click on artillery link, drag the scrubber.

Now you will hear overlapping sound of the previously unloaded “armored” grandchild swf being played along with that artillery swf's sound.

```
     //CUSTOM event sent by child swf, once grandchild swf is loaded
stage.addEventListener("playGrandchildScrubber", disableScrubberF);


function disableScrubberF(e:Event):void
{
var grandChildMC:MovieClip = thisMC.myLoader.content;
var actualTrackLengthGC : Number = ((scrubberMC.scrubBarMC.width) - (scrubberMC.scrubHandleMC.width));
var animLengthGC : int = grandChildMC.totalFrames;
var leftBoundGC : Number = scrubberMC.scrubBarMC.x;
var rightBoundGC : Number = scrubberMC.scrubBarMC.x + actualTrackLengthGC;
var dragBoundGC : Rectangle = new Rectangle(leftBoundGC, scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.y, actualTrackLengthGC, 0);
var calcWidthGC : Number = actualTrackLength/grandChildMC.totalFrames;

//sets the value of boolean "grandChildSwfLoaded" to true, indicating gradchild swf has been loaded.    
grandChildSwfLoaded = true; 

//Hides scrubberhandle, totoal time and current time, fill of CHILD TIMELINE SCRUBBER. GRANDCHILD TIMELINE SCRUBBER HANDLE
//CURRENT TIME AND TOTOAL TIME BECOME VISIBLE.
currentTimeGC.visible= true;
totalTimeGC.visible=true;
totaltime.visible = false;
currentTime.visible = false;
scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.visible = true;
scrubberMC.scrubHandleMC.visible = false;
scrubberMC.fill_mcGC.visible = true;
scrubberMC.fill_mc.visible = false;


    //CODE FOR CURRENT TIME OF GRAND CHILD SWF
    var totalSeconds = Math.floor(grandChildMC.totalFrames / 24);
    var input = totalSeconds;
    var totalAnimTime = (input > 3600 ? Math.floor(input/3600) + ':':'') 
    +(input%3600 < 600 ? '0':'')+Math.floor(input%3600/60)+':' 
    +(input%60 < 10 ? '0':'')+input%60;
    totalTimeGC.text = " / " + totalAnimTime;



//thisMC refers to child swf, i.e., overview swf
thisMC.stop();
animationPlaying = false;

grandChildMC.play();
grandchildAnimationPlaying = true


scrubberMC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScrubberGC);

scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.x = leftBoundGC;
scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.buttonMode = true;

     scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseEventsGC);


        function handleMouseEventsGC(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        switch(String(evt.type)) {

        //following work is done when you hold the mouse down.
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN:
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playScrubGC);
        scrubberMC.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScrubberGC);
        scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.startDrag(false, dragBoundGC);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseEventsGC);
        grandChildMC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrubMovieGC);
        if (grandchildAnimationPlaying) grandChildMC.stop();
        break;


        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:
        scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.stopDrag();
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseEventsGC);
        grandChildMC.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrubMovieGC);

        if (grandchildAnimationPlaying) grandChildMC.play();
        grandchildAnimationPlaying = true;
        scrubberMC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScrubberGC);


        pp.play_btn.visible = false;
        pp.pause_btn.visible = true;

        if (grandChildMC.currentLabel == "swfComplete") {

                //disable pause button on last frame
                disablePause_mc.visible=true;


            } else {

                //enable pause button on all frames except last frame
                disablePause_mc.visible=false;

            }
            if (grandChildMC.currentFrame==grandChildMC.totalFrames) {

            grandChildMC.stop();
            }else{
                 grandChildMC.play();
            }
        if (grandChildMC.currentFrame > grandChildMC.totalFrames) {
            scrubberMC.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScrubberGC);
        }


        break;

        }
        }

        function scrubMovieGC(evt:Event):void
        {

        scrubberMC.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScrubberGC);
        var scrubPosGC : int = scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.x;
        var calcWidthGC : Number = actualTrackLengthGC/grandChildMC.totalFrames;    
        var gotoFrameGC : int = Math.ceil(scrubPosGC /calcWidthGC);
        thisMC.stop()
        grandChildMC.gotoAndStop(gotoFrameGC);
        }


        function updateScrubberGC(evt:Event):void
        {

        var percentGC : Number = ((grandChildMC.currentFrame)/(grandChildMC.totalFrames));
        scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.x = percentGC * actualTrackLengthGC;
        scrubberMC.fill_mcGC.width = percentGC * actualTrackLengthGC;

        //CODE FOR CURRENT TIME OF GRAND CHILD SWF
        var currentSeconds = Math.floor(grandChildMC.currentFrame/24);
        var CurrentInput = currentSeconds;
        var timeElapsed = (CurrentInput > 3600 ? Math.floor(CurrentInput/3600) + ':':'') //hours
        +(CurrentInput%3600 < 600 ? '0':'')+Math.floor(CurrentInput%3600/60)+':' //minutes
        +(CurrentInput%60 < 10 ? '0':'')+CurrentInput%60; //seconds
        currentTimeGC.text = timeElapsed;

        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playScrubGC);
        function playScrubGC(event:Event):void{

            var percentGC : Number = ((grandChildMC.currentFrame)/(grandChildMC.totalFrames));
            var actualTrackLengthGC : Number = ((scrubberMC.scrubBarMC.width) - (scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.width));
            scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.x = percentGC * actualTrackLengthGC;
            scrubberMC.fill_mcGC.width = percentGC * actualTrackLengthGC;
            var scrubPosGC : int = scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.x;
            var calcWidthGC : Number = actualTrackLengthGC/grandChildMC.totalFrames;    
            var gotoFrameGC : uint = Math.round(scrubPosGC/calcWidthGC);


            //CODE FOR CURRENT TIME OF GRAND CHILD SWF
            var currentSeconds = Math.floor(grandChildMC.currentFrame/24);
            var CurrentInput = currentSeconds;
            var timeElapsed = (CurrentInput > 3600 ? Math.floor(CurrentInput/3600) + ':':'') //hours
            +(CurrentInput%3600 < 600 ? '0':'')+Math.floor(CurrentInput%3600/60)+':' //minutes
            +(CurrentInput%60 < 10 ? '0':'')+CurrentInput%60; //seconds

            currentTimeGC.text = timeElapsed;

        }


        }


        stage.addEventListener("enableChildScrubberDisableGrandchildScrubber", enableScrubberF);

        function enableScrubberF(e:Event):void
        {

            currentTimeGC.visible= false;
            totalTimeGC.visible=false;
            totaltime.visible = true;
            currentTime.visible = true;

            scrubberMC.scrubHandleMCGC.visible = false;
            scrubberMC.scrubHandleMC.visible = true;
            scrubberMC.fill_mcGC.visible = false;
            scrubberMC.fill_mc.visible = true;

        }
```

Comment: Drop timeline coding period.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get you, if I don't write code on timeline, then where should I write code? are you suggesting seperate actionscript file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See, the timeline code has its tricks regarding initialization of its vars, also all the code you write on a certain frame gets executed whenever you go to that frame, be it normal playback or `gotoAndStop()` call. This makes your vars reinitialized, including additional load request, and other objects in display are reconstructed as well, this leads to various bugs. A separate AS3 file without any timeline coding is more reliable because you are in complete control of code flow and variable handling. Also consider making your MCs into sprites if you need them to be persistent

Comment: ...and leave those animated MCs as children of the controlling sprites, so that their animation will not interfere with variable allocation and other code flow (aka separating code from visuals).

Comment: Please someone help. SoundMixer.stopAll would not work as it mutes all the sounds including currently playing grandchild's sound. Same is the case with sound transform. ANY IDEA WHAT IS CAUSING THIS ISSUE. WHAT IS THE ROOT CAUSE?

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick reply. To be honest, it seems like a big ask bcoz I have never written a separate actionscript file. Is there no other option.